# Vertically center a child <div> within a parent <div> when parent has display: block;

Tags: javascript, html, css, vertical-alignment

I am trying to vertically center a child div that has `contenteditable` so users may type in the middle of the parent div, so the text needs to be vertically centered.

**The parent div must have it's display set to `block`** because I need it's top and bottom borders to have the max height of it's container, as it will be selected for a resizing event.

I have tried many methods such as flexbox and vertical align but they all require me to change the parent's display property which I can't see any way around. I'll even accept a JS solution if it works and isn't too cumbersome.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-width: 100px;
  outline: none;
}

.parent {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  
}

.child {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 80px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" align="center">
  
  <div contenteditable=true class="child">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you position it absolutely? `top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it would be to use these CSS rules:

```
.parent {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

See complete solution:
http://codepen.io/shippin/pen/yMKMpR

Also note you have some issues in your html:

- missing quotes on contenteditable="true"
- The  align attribute is not supported in HTML5.

Comment: This works! So I accepted it. But do you know if there is anything I can do about the new divs being created everytime you hit enter? I'm not really liking that

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know what you mean about new divs being created?

Comment: Sorry that was just an issue in my own code, I fixed it by removing `overflow: auto;`